# Propagate X-B3-TraceId between applications using SNS and SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-aws, aws-sdk-java

I have 2 spring based applications both of them uses spring-sleuth.

**Application-1:**

```
AmazonSNS snsPublisher;
snsPublisher.publish(message)
```

I would like to add MDC context here somehow, so that application-2 can use the same context. Is there any integration that is provided to achieve this ?

**Application-2:**

```
@SqsListener
public void process(String message, @Headers Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> sqsHeaders)
```

When I receive the MDC context(traceId) set by other application in headers, then I need an integration which can add that same MDC context in application-2 as well. So that, when I look at logs I will have a whole picture of what has happened with that request combining both of these applications.

Comment: Spring sleuth support this feature out of the box https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/pull/1218/files